# Just Links click event - firing triggers not working

Tags: google-tag-manager

screenshot of red crosses

[image: 1]

I'm new to GTM and at the beginning of setting up my first click event using a UA tag and a variable containing my tracking ID. That part fires ok. I created a simple Just Links trigger set to All Link Clicks. But when I debug with preview, I get 'Link Click' ok in the left summary, but it says tags not fired - my GA tag and inside the Firing Triggers haven't worked. There's red crosses against All Pages and the gtm filters. I've triple checked all my settings against tutorials I've followed but have no idea when the Firing Triggers have not worked?

[existing tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv6cR.jpg)

[existing trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muNNl.jpg)

[new tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0lkJ.jpg)

[preview firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tXSl.jpg)

Comment: have you published any version of the container, or is this a new container that has never been published to prod?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the preview mode you see the red cross. It will help us a lot. Thanks

Comment: Hi, yes container is published. I'm adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error from your trigger.

Your current trigger is `pageView in all page`

So you need to create an `trigger` For `Just Link`

[image]

Step1 : Change type to `Just Links`

Step2 : Give an appropriate name for this trigger.

Step3 : Save and change your tag's trigger to this one.

I believe this will work !

Just remember :

Tag is `what` you are sending.

Trigger is `when` you are sending.

---

Add :

[image]

From the comment. I guess the problem is we need to create another tag for tracking `Link Click`.

Since you original tag is for tracking `Page View`. We need to have 2 tags for your scenario.

In the event tracking. There are 3 level :
Category > Action > Label

You can come up with your own structure on this.

The screenshot is just providing a general one.

Especially for the label, You can decide whether using `{{click text}}` or `{{click url}}`

Comment: Thanks Darrellwan. I haven't changed anything yet, let me say what I did. So I have a general GA UA tag for all pages, this returns my regular GA page data. Then I created a Trigger for Just Links to capture page links. I'm a bit unclear about what I should change? If I change my GA UA tag to Just Links, how do I capture my regular GA data? I'm adding extra screenshots. Thanks

Comment: hi @upat7 . In these 2 screenshot, you have a page_view tag and it's correct because the trigger is fire on all pages. So I guess you need another tag for tracking event, I will update the answer with how to add the tag for tracking link  click

Comment: Thanks again Darrellwan. I'm getting there. I have a firing click links tag now, but no real time events data? I'm adding two new screenshots of my new tag and preview.

Comment: Action, label, value were a bit of a mystery to me, I need to read up more about these?

Comment: Update, I've got it working in GA real time > events - I can see a link event. However, it doesn't show the url I clicked, even though I clicked to a different page on the site.

Comment: Update, I've fixed that bit now by changing the label, brilliant, thanks.

Comment: For the click related. You might enable the {{click url}} variable. You can accept this answer if you think this it's helping. Thanks